# Can't connect to GCP VM Permission denied (publickey) error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine

I'm creating a new VM instance. I've clean all the meta data. Then I'm running the following command in the cloud shell:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "europe-west2-c" "vmname"  --project "myprojectname"
```

then I've been asking to enter a passphrase (which I don't know). I press enter until I get the following error `Permission denied (publickey) error`

I've delete and recreated my instance multiple time but I always have the same error. What should I do?

Comment: This looks like an error in your local environment (where you are running the gcloud command) rather than an issue with the VM. Is this situation happening with all VMS 
across all projects or only with this one? What are your IAM roles in the project? Also,  what do you see on the serial console of your VM?

Comment: Did you try to remove (or simply move) the content of your `~/.ssh` directory

Comment: @Simon Breton, Can you accept and upvote one of the below answers which best suits to your question? If you still not agree with these answers, post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

1. Logon using UI ssh. This creates an ephemeral ssh key, Google Agent also executes the codepath to refresh .ssh/authorized_keys and address any invalid dir/file permissions for both .ssh/ and .ssh/authorized_keys. This approach will address common gcloud compute ssh issues that relates to corrupted keys, missing dir/file or invalid dir/file permission. Try the gcloud again after performing the UI ssh.
2. Make sure that account has authenticated to gcloud as an IAM user with the [compute instance admin role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.instanceAdmin.v1); for example, run gcloud auth revoke --all, gcloud auth login [IAM-USER] then try gcloud compute ssh again.
3. Verify that persistent SSH Keys metadata for gcloud is set for either the project or instance. Look in **Compute Engine > Metadata**, then click **SSH Keys**. Persistent keys **do not have** the *expireOn attribute*.
4. It's possible the account has lost the private key, mismatched a keypair, etc. You can force gcloud to generate a new SSH keypair by doing the following:
   Move ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine and ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub if present.
   For example:
   mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub.old
   mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.old
   Try gcloud compute ssh [INSTANCE-NAME] again. A new keypair will be created and the public key will be added to the SSH keys metadata.
5. Verify that the Linux Google Agent scripts are installed, up-to-date, and running. See [Determining Google Agent Status](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#wgei_console_logs). If the Linux Google Agent is not installed, re-install it. See [guest-environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment).
6. Verify account home owner/permission is correct. Make sure that account home directory has the correct ownership and is not globally writable. If not using os-login (which is default), your's .ssh folder must have mode 0700, .ssh/authorized_keys file must have mode 0600. Review /var/log/auth.log for any errors.
   **Commands:**
   sudo chmod 700 /home/[user-id]/.ssh
   sudo chmod 600 /home/[user-id]/.ssh/authorized_keys
7. If os-login is enabled and the Virtual Machine instance is using a service account (default). Add the following roles to the account.
   roles/compute.osLogin
   roles/iam.serviceAccountUser

For more information [troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#common_ssh_errors).

Comment: item 2 covers 99% of cases.

Answer (score 0):

The possible causes for a Permission denied (publickey) error are:

- Your key expired and Compute Engine deleted your
  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
- You used an SSH key stored in metadata to connect to a VM that has
  OS Login enabled.
- You used an SSH key stored in an OS Login profile to connect to a VM
  that doesn't have OS Login enabled.
- You connected using a third-party tool and your SSH command is
  misconfigured.
- The sshd daemon isn't running or isn't configured properly.

You can find more information on how to troubleshoot SSH key errors in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#permission_denied)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue sometimes . Cause and solution according to GCP troubleshooting [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) is:

> Your key expired and Compute Engine deleted your
> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. If you manually added SSH keys to your VM
> and then connected to your VM using the Google Cloud Console, Compute
> Engine created a new key pair for your connection. After the new key
> pair expired, Compute Engine deleted your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file
> in the VM, which included your manually added SSH key.
>
> To resolve this issue, try one of the following:
>
> Connect to your VM using the Google Cloud Console or the gcloud
> command-line tool. Re-add your SSH key to metadata. For more information, see Add SSH keys to VMs that use metadata-based SSH keys.

I use terraform so in this case I instructed the workflow to destroy the VM and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue when you cannot start ssh:

1. Edit VM and enable Serial port
2. Start serial console
3. Edit ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
4. On your desktop/client,

   - edit /Users/[yourdesktopuser]/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   - copy contents to clipboard
   - Paste this content to the end of authorized_keys file in the VM serial console
   - Save and close

This will then recognize the public key from your desktop